# Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy (CORP) error while serving static files Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm serving static files with Express like this:

```
app.use('/uploads/users/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', 'users/images')));
```

But these files don't show on my frontend application, instead this error message shows up

```
The resource at “http://localhost:8080/uploads/users/images/1670518070063.jpg” was blocked due to its Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy header (or lack thereof). See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)#
```

I'm also using the cors dependency from npm in this way

```
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }))
...
...
route definitions
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read more about this HTTP header in the MDN web docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)), and found that this header can have the next values (same-site, same-origin, and cross-origin).

I fixed the error by setting the header manually in my uploads route:

```
app.use('/uploads', (_, res, next) => {
    res.set('Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy', 'cross-origin');
    next();
  })
...
app.use('/uploads/users/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', 'users/images')));
```

Although there is a warning due to a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1074261) when serving PDF files

Answer (score -3):

I don't recall having to configure CORS at all the last time I stoof up Express and used it to serve static files. [The documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) say to do it like this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

or this

```
const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```